# How to disable [marquee] tag with CSS? Is this possible?

Tags: html, css, marquee

I have inherited an app where users can insert their own HTML responses. I can only set a global CSS file and a global JS file for this app. Recently, some of the users have awakened an ancient evil, known as the `<marquee>` and `<blink>` tags.

I can't strip the tags out on input or output, could I at least disarm them with a CSS rule?

```
blink {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The above gets rid of the blinking effect, is there a similar way to disable the marquee effect with CSS?

If worst comes to worst, I could use `marquee { display:none }`, but sometimes the users put useful information in that tag; I don't have enough leverage there to argue "if it's marquee, it's unimportant by definition" (which has been a good enough approximation elsewhere).

Or am I trying to solve a non-technical problem by technical means, and should I educate the (internal) users on the Evils That Shall Not Be Invoked?

---

As it turns out, there is no CSS-only, cross-browser solution; I'll have to go the harder, JS way - probably replace marquee with span.

Comment: You can't strip tags?!  Isn't that a massive security hole?

Comment: As I recall, !important binds in reverse order and you can trump user !important with global !important. This was done so that the top level CSS file (which resides in browser configuration) could override any setting. This is normally used in configuring the browser for accessibility.

Comment: @RichieHindle: True that; and if I could, I'd go that way. However, some probems aren't technical in nature (such as "no, we won't approve that change, since nothing bad can ever happen in our fantasy world")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no CSS only cross-browser solution for that. The relevant properties were first introduced in [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/). Some user agents may have already implemented it. For instance, in Webkit you can use the [`-webkit-marquee*` properties](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/scrolling-text-with-webkit-marquee/). In Gecko, setting [`-moz-binding: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-binding) works as well, though its original purpose is different.

Otherwise, hiding all `marquee`s at all indicates users not to use that element since it's no longer working.

Anyway, you can replace all `marquee` elements in the DOM to `span`s with JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Does this work for you?

```
marquee { overflow:visible; -moz-binding:none; }
```

For more visit [Disabling deprecated html using css](http://monc.se/kitchen/140/disabling-deprecated-html-using-css).